# How do I detect data that only appears in dom?

Tags: ruby, selenium, dom, capybara

So I am looking at a form field that occasional fails to fill in with data

```
.set('Important Label')       #occasionally ignored
.send_keys('Important Label') #occasionally ignored
```

Here is how the element looks in html, with or without the field filled

```
<input data-bind="textinput: form.name, errorInput: form.hasNameError"
placeholder="Name" class="form-control name-blah-form" type="text">
```

The only place I can see the data is in the DOM view by Mozilla Firebug

[image]

Various finds I have attempted come up with `ElementNotFound`

```
find(:xpath, '*//[contains(@value,"Important Label")]') #ElementNotFound
find(:xpath, '*//[contains(value,"Important Label")]')  #ElementNotFound 
find(:xpath, '*//[contains(text(),"Important Label")]') #ElementNotFound
find(:xpath, '*//[@value="Important Label"]')           #ElementNotFound
find(:xpath, '*//[value="Important Label"]')            #ElementNotFound
```

This type of form field comes up in a number of places.  Detecting what is in the field would be a great help.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Seems that your `form` located inside an `iframe`, that's why `webdriver` cannot `find` it. If it really so, you should switch to that `iframe` before handling your `input` field...also, check correctness of your `XPath`: I guess `'*\\[contains(@value,"Important Label")]')` should be `'//*[contains(@value,"Important Label")]')`

Comment: Thanks, typed that bit from memory so it was ```//``` also there are in fact 2 iframes, and both are accounted for.

Comment: Technically you probably want `.//*` most of the time, otherwise it defeats the use of `within` and find scoping -  see https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#beware-the-xpath--trap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filling in the fields value changes the value property not the value attribute.  The HTML shows the attribute (value when page loaded), not the property (current value). To match on the property you can use the `with` option of the field selector - https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/selector.rb#L67

```
find(:field, with: 'Important Label')
```

Comment: received an error ```invalid keys :with, should be one of :count, :minimum, :maximum, :between,``` ```:text, :id, :class, :visible, :exact, :match, :wait, :filter_set (ArgumentError)```

Comment: @TangibleDream  What exactly was the code you tried to use? and what version of Capybara.  That list of options doesn't match the `field` selector so I'm guessing you didn't actually use what I showed.

Comment: ```find(:xpath, [xpath], with: title) ```
```capybara (2.10.2)```

Comment: @TangibleDream As I stated, the `with` option is available on the `field` selector -- hence the `:field` as the first option to find.

Comment: @TangibleDream Did this work for you when using the `field` selector?

Comment: As per usual, the problem didn't reappear to get caught.  However, your command doesn't break it either.  So I'm calling it the correct answer.  If I catch it working, I'll add comment, likewise if it breaks.